# 10 Gbit Network without Additional Switch

Tags: ethernet

I've a question about my current setup:

[image: My Topology]

I don't want to buy additional 10G SFP+ switch. May I use R710's new Intel 10G Ethernet's second port to connect additional servers into my network? What is the best way to configure them without buying a new switch? I just want to use their additional port, to connect them into router without any costs.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did the answer help you? If yes, please accept it, so that your question does not keep popping up on the homepage. Alternatively, you could provide your own answer and accept that.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> May I use R710's new Intel 10G Ethernet's second port to connect additional servers into my network?

Your question lacks detail. Both SFP+ ports on the servers represent different NICs. With that chain you need the servers to bridge or route. This may be possible but host configurations are off-topic here.

> What is the best way to configure them without buying a new switch?

"The best way" depends on your requirements you've not told us about. The chained setup in your diagram has multiple single points of failure and may be less reliable than you require.

Consider the cost of failure in your setup (a server fails and needs repair or replacement) and reconsider buying a switch.

Best practice for high availability would be to use *two 10G switches* and connect each server and router to each switch.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zac! What I am trying to do is that:

- Making all R710s online by the router of internet.
- Connectiong all R710s into other devices that connected into router - like my NAS drive.

What you mean in here - server failure - is something that I never think about yet. So, I'll deff consider this.

Comment: I was trying to point out that the two server SFP+ ports are not like adjacent switch ports. Instead, they are two NICs that do not forward anything between themselves but require the server software to do so.